# Use PayPal IPN with iOS PayPal library

Tags: ios, objective-c, paypal, paypal-ipn

I integrated the PayPal iOS library, but I noticed, that it is not I am not able to work with IPN. Is there a secure workaround or isn't it possible at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dave from PayPal here.

The PayPal iOS SDK uses the new PayPal REST APIs to communicate with PayPal's servers. Unfortunately, these APIs do not currently work with IPN.

At some point in the future this situation will improve, but we don't yet have an estimated date.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the answer. I hope that you release this in the near feature, because this makes things alot easier. Anyway, till then I have to find another way…